# Using babel / browserslist to give *not* supported fallback messages

Tags: babeljs, babel-polyfill, babel-preset-env

Is there any hook or plugin that one can use as part of the Babel-verse (e.g., @babel/preset-env, using a plugin of Rollup with browserslist, as a hook within core-js, etc.) which will detect *lack* of support for the targeted features or lack of being present within the targeted browser range and allow one to hook into this information to redirect one's application to a generic not supported page (if not one customized to the specific lacking features)?

All of the efforts to minimize what is actually bundled (e.g., preset-env's `useBuiltins`) are less of a draw to take advantage of if there is no way to have some assurance that if one is too aggressive in excluding browsers, that such users will at least be alerted to the browsers which can support the composite application.